# Javascript adding to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like this, that contains a lot more data than what is present but this is just a small sample.

I am iterating through the object and checking if EmployeeLocations = object. If it does, I would like to add that to a new array along with the nested value. For example, "EmployeeLocationA : FL HQ" would be added to the array, "EmployeeLocationB" : "New York", "DoorsA" : 345, would be added and so forth.

This object will be joined with the values of the  original object and returned.

```
{
  "Building": 4,
  "Doors":{
   "a": 345,
   "b": 87,
   "c": 98
  }
  "EmployeeId": 565,
  "EmployeeLocation": {
    "a": "FL HQ",
    "b": "New York",
    "c": "Chicago"
  },
```

I am able to iterate and get the following information, but I am unable to add it to the array. What I am trying to get back is an array that looks like this:

```
 "Building": 4, "DoorsA": 345, "DoorB": 87, "DoorsC": 98, "EmployeeId": 565, "EmployeeLocationA": "FL HQ", "EmployeeLocationB": "New York", "EmployeeLocationC": "Chicago" ,
```

```
  Object.keys(Details).forEach((key, value) => {
    if(typeof( Details[key]) === 'object' ){
      const objPositions = Details[key]; // holds inner values
      console.log("objposition " + objPositions[key] + allDetails[key])
      console.log("---->" + key + "X " + objPositions.x);
      console.log("---->" + key + "Y " + objPositions.y);
      console.log("---->" + key + "Z " + objPositions.z);
      let xKey = key + "X"
      arr.push(key + "X" , objPositions.x)
     // arr.push(xKey.toString() : objPositions.x.toString())
```

I am really new at javascript and am having big trouble with it. Can someone shed a little light? Thanks

Comment: You say array, but it's an object, so which is it?

Comment: Why are you using `Object.keys(Details).forEach`?

Comment: It is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: a more dynamic solution that flattens it dynamically:

```js
const data = {
    "Building": 4,
    "Doors": { "a": 345, "b": 87, "c": 98 },
    "EmployeeId": 565,
    "EmployeeLocation": {
        "a": "FL HQ",
        "b": "New York",
        "c": "Chicago"
    }
};

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((p, c) => {
    if (typeof data[c] === 'object') {
        const tmp = Object.keys(data[c]).reduce((x, y) => ({ ...x, [c + y.toUpperCase()]: data[c][y] }), {});
        return { ...p, ...tmp };
    }
    return { ...p, [c]: data[c] }; 
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

---

Not sure why you are using `Object.keys` to loop over your object.

But to give you a general idea, this should give you the expected outcome:

```js
const data = {
    "Building": 4,
    "Doors": { "a": 345, "b": 87, "c": 98 },
    "EmployeeId": 565,
    "EmployeeLocation": {
        "a": "FL HQ",
        "b": "New York",
        "c": "Chicago"
    }
}

if (typeof data.EmployeeLocation === 'object') {
    Object.keys(data.EmployeeLocation).forEach(k => {
        data['EmployeeLocation' + k.toUpperCase()] = data.EmployeeLocation[k];
    });
}
  
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I need to add the data to a new object or does this one add it to data?

Comment: I'ts added to `data`, should I change it to a new object?

Comment: That is fine, is there another way to check the data for a nested object than using the property name? There are a lot.

Comment: Please see my edit, I've made a dynamic solution that works on all keys, is this wat you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to flatten an object

```js
const obj = {
  Building: 4,
  Doors: {
    a: 345,
    b: 87,
    c: 98,
  },
  EmployeeId: 565,
  EmployeeLocation: {
    a: "FL HQ",
    b: "New York",
    c: "Chicago",
  },
};

const newObject = flatten(obj);

console.log(newObject);

function flatten(obj, prefix) {
  const newObject = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      Object.assign(newObject, flatten(value, key));
    } else {
      newObject[prefix ? prefix + key.toUpperCase() : key] = value;
    }
  });
  return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```js
const obj = {
  "Building": 4,
  "Doors":{
   "a": 345,
   "b": 87,
   "c": 98
  },
  "EmployeeId": 565,
  "EmployeeLocation": {
    "a": "FL HQ",
    "b": "New York",
    "c": "Chicago"
  },
}

const solObj = {}

for(const key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
        const childObj = obj[key];
        for(const childKey in childObj){
            solObj[key+childKey]= childObj[childKey];
        }
    }else{
        solObj[key]=obj[key];
    }
}
console.log(solObj)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).